# Proof in Apostol Polynomial Zeros

Tags: polynomials

If $f(a)=0$ and $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n\geq1$, show that $f(x)=(x-a)h(x)$, where $h$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$.

I can't figure this proof out.  Will someone help?

Comment: Anyway, are you familiar with the Division Theorem? or the Remainder Theorem?

Comment: Oh, yes:  f(x)=(x-a)h(x), and n is the highest degree of f.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the Remainder Theorem; however, I cannot use it to prove this assertion, as the proof of this assertion is the proof of that theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a substitution? Substitute $x=y+a$ in $f(x)$ to get $f(y+a)$, a polynomial in $y$. Let's denote it by $g(y)$.

$$f(y+a)=g(y) $$

For $y=0$ we get 
$$g(0) = f(0+a) = f(a) = 0$$

So $g(y)$ is a polynomial in $y$ that takes value $0$ for $y=0$. But that means the free term of $g(y)$ is $0$ and so 
$$g(y)= y \cdot e(y)$$

Recall that $g(y)=f(y+a)$ and we get

$$f(y+a) = y e(y)$$

Now use $y+a=x$ or $y=x-a$ in the equation above and get

$$f(x) = (x-a) e(x-a)$$

Now denote $e(x-a)$ by $h(x)$.

Comment: That's it.  Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Using this substitution you can also prove the Division Theorem.

Comment: May I ask how long you've been a math student?  When you first began studying Calculus, would this have been as easy as it is now?